# How can I fix the v-app-bar to top when use with v-system-bar and set hide-on-scroll?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

also when scroll up how can i totally hide the v-app-bar ?

https://codepen.io/curedovahkiin/pen/jOyGVow

```
#app

#app-template
  v-app  
    v-system-bar(height="30" app dark absolute) 
    v-app-bar( height="80" color="red"  flat app hide-on-scroll ) 
    v-main
      div(style="height:1000px")
```

```
const App = {
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    //
  })
}


new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML template:

```
#app-template
v-app  
  v-system-bar(height="30" app dark v-if="top")
  v-app-bar( height="80" color="red" flat app hide-on-scroll)
  v-main
    div(id="asdf" style="height:1000px")
```

Javascript:

```
const App = {
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    top: true
  }),
  mounted() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var vm = this;

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ // or window.addEventListener("scroll"....
      var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
      vm.top = lastScrollTop <= 5 ? true : false
    }, false);
  }
}


new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this makes hide-on-scoll disabled, v-app-bar should show when scroll up

Comment: I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/andref94/pen/qBRPmMQ) where v-app-bar is hidden when scrolling down and shown when scrolling up. It's correct or am I missing something?

Comment: anyway it's worked, however I want a native vuetify solution, if there isn't ,i'll take this solution 

Comment: I made some small changes to the codepen. Now on `v-app-bar` you have only the prop `hide-on-scroll` and the behaviuor of the component is the same as before. But you can't remove the listener from `mounted` method, because it's needed for setting the `v-if` on the `v-system-bar`. Whitout the `v-if`, when you scroll down you would see a part of the `v-app-bar` of the same height of the `v-system-bar`

Comment: yes, i have do things just like this,and set ```vm.top = lastScrollTop <= 30 ? true : false```  will be more soomthy